# jQuery: Get one of a set of selected elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are several elements that are selected by `$(".foo")`.  `$(".foo").text()` returns the text of each element concatenated together. I just want the text of one element. What is the best way to do this?

`$(".foo")[0].text()` fails.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want to use [`.eq(0)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/), like this:

```
$(".foo").eq(0).text()
```

When you do `$(".foo")[0]` or `$(".foo").get(0)` you're getting the **DOM Element**, not the **jQuery object**, [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) will get the jQuery object, which has the [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method.

Answer (score 2):

Normally using the `#` selector syntax selects *one* element by `id` attribute value. Do you have more than one element with the same `id` attribute value? If so, then you need to correct your HTML. `id` attribute values should be *unique* within a document.

Comment: Given the example is `#foo`, I think this was a question oversight, rather than the actual issue...

Answer (score 1):

The items in the jQuery array always return the dom elements (not the jQuery wrapped elements). You could do something like:

```
$($("#foo")[0]).text()
```

Comment: This is a much more expensive way to go about it :)